# Excel - image to fit the size of merged cell

Tags: excel, vb.net

Is there any way to fit the image into the cell. I have template in excel with field "FpPicture" which is

[image: Image in yellow box]

Tried to put image in yellow box as

```
oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").Select()
Dim new_size_image As New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(paths_full),
                     oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Width,
                     oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Height)
new_size_image.Save("123.bmp")
oSheet.Pictures.Insert("123.bmp")
```

It seems like mergearea.width for some reason doesnt take entire length.

Same here

```
Dim pic As Object
oSheet.Range("FPPICTURE").Select()
pic = oExcel.ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(paths_sig)
With pic
    .Top = oExcel.ActiveCell.Top + 5
    .Left = oExcel.ActiveCell.Left + 5
    .Width = oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Width
    .Height = oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Height
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was simple. 1 point = 1.33 pixels

[image: PIXELS]

Just changed to code

```
oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").Select()
Dim new_size_image As New Bitmap(Image.FromFile(paths_full),
                     oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Width * 1.33,
                     oSheet.Range("fppICTURE").MergeArea.Height * 1.33)
new_size_image.Save("123.bmp")
oSheet.Pictures.Insert("123.bmp")
```